# Outputting binary data by using PHP Header

Tags: php, header, binary

I am having a problem to output binary data by using PHP's header and can't figure out why, would you please help?

(the form)

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

(the PHP script)

```
<?php

require_once "connection.php";

$pic = $_FILES['fileToUpload'];

$pic_info = getimagesize($pic['tmp_name']);
$pic_mime_type = $pic_info['mime'];
$pic_data = file_get_contents($pic['tmp_name']);
$pic_size = $pic['size'];

header("Content-type: " . $pic_mime);
header("Content-length: " . $pic_size);

echo $pic_data;
?>
```

The output of the script is just an empty squre, would you please help?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are You sure the upload actually succeeded? You don't check anything here. I suggest reading up [Handling File Uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) manual section and adding a few checks here, this may give You an idea what went wrong. Also may be a good idea to use **[readfile](http://php.net/readfile)** instead of file_get_contents+echo

Comment: Make sure your file is uploaded and i am not sure about the 'size' key in your $pic array. Not sure that the size is returned by getimagesize()

Comment: Thanks Poncha and Andreas, thanks to Martin, problem solved :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using

```
header("Content-type: " . $pic_mime);
```

instead of

```
header("Content-type: " . $pic_mime_type);
```

and make sure that connection.php doesn't output anything, as it is parsed before the headers are sent.
http://www.php.net/manual/function.header.php

example of **connection.php**
**bad**

```
<html>
<?php
echo 'foo';
?>
```

**good**

```
<?php
$result = 'bar';
```

- no HTML-code (or anything else before the opening `<?php` tag)
- no `echo` (or `print`, or `print_f`, or anything that sends data back)
- no closing `?>` tag (and therefore no unintended whitespace after it)

Also take a look at [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php?rq=1).

Comment: Sorry Martin, typo :(, but even corrected it back to "$pic_mime_type", it still doesn't work, any idea? thanks for your help

Comment: I tried it over here and it's working quite well. I just had to remove `require_once "connection.php";`, because I'm don't know what this is doing. Also it's possible that this is the error reason if it returns data (a blank after `?>` is enough) you can't send headers afterwards. That's why you shouldn't use close the php tag at all in include files.

Comment: Thanks very very much Martin, I have totally no idea what to do so I follow what you said, remove the "connection.php" and also remove the "?>" tag at the end. With or without the "?>" won't affect anything, but the "connection.php" does. It just a file of connecting the server and database. That is where the problem arise, do you know why it cause a problem? It's just a script that's about the server name, username, password and database name. Really thanks for you help.

Comment: Thank you so much Martin, really appreciate :) Have a nice day!

Comment: You're welcome. Mind voting on the answer and/or accepting it?